# Taking in input for Calculator program

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I want the program to accept operation signs (+, -, * ,/) as input. Whenever I do that it throws an exception. Can anybody help me fix this problem and make the program accept one of these signs as input.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator
{
    private double solution;
    private static double x, y;
    private static char ops;

    public static interface Calculate
    {
        public abstract double operation(double x, double y);
    }

    public static class addition implements Calculate
    {
       public double operation(double x, double y){
         return(x+y);
       }
    }

    public static class subtraction implements Calculate
    {
       public double operation(double x, double y){
         return(x-y);
       }
    }

    public static class multiplication implements Calculate
    {
       public double operation(double x, double y){
         return(x*y);
       }
    }

    public static class division implements Calculate
    {
       public double operation(double x, double y){
         return(x/y);
       }
  }

    public void calc(int ops){
         Scanner operands = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("operand 1: ");
         x = operands.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("operand 2: ");
         y = operands.nextDouble();

         System.out.println("Solution: ");

         Calculate [] jumpTable = new Calculate[4];
         jumpTable['+'] = new addition();
         jumpTable['-'] = new subtraction();
         jumpTable['*'] = new multiplication();
         jumpTable['/'] = new division();

         solution = jumpTable[ops].operation(x, y);

         System.out.println(solution);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("What operation? ('+', '-', '*', '/')");
      System.out.println(" Enter 0 for Addition");
      System.out.println(" Enter 1 for Subtraction");
      System.out.println(" Enter 2 for Multiplication");
      System.out.println(" Enter 3 for Division");

      Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);
      ops = operation.next().charAt(0);

      Calculator calc = new Calculator();
      calc.calc(ops);
  }
}
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 43
at Calculator.calc(Calculator.java:54)
at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:76)
```

Comment: What do you think `jumpTable['+']` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jumpTable['+']
```

will be translated to the ASCII code (43) of the `+` sign (it's converted to a `char`), leaving you with a number out of the 0-4 range. You probably want to use actual numeric indices (or make sure your array can contain the highest numerical representation for your set of char values, in this case 47 by `/`).

ASCII [table](http://www.asciitable.com/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I figured it translated to ASCII code but I forgot to make the jumpTable's capacity greater then 47. Changing the 4 to 50 in `Calculate [] jumpTable = new Calculate[4];` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reference `jumpTable` by 0..3 indices. But you're trying to reference it by '+' sign which is beyond this scope. Consider using `HashMap<String, Calculate>` for storing operations in such way:

```
Map<String, Calculate> jumpTable = new HashMap<String, Calculate>();
jumpTable.put("+", new addition());
jumpTable.put("-", new subtraction());
jumpTable.put("*", new multiplication());
jumpTable.put("/", new division());

String operation = Character.toString((char) ops);
solution = jumpTable.get(operation).operation(x, y);
```